# Magento Error creating Credit Memo

Tags: magento

Magento version 1.7.2

When we’re creating a credit memo we get the following error:

Cannot save the credit memo.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: You provided too less information to correctly identify the problem. Could you check Magento logs (in var/log) for any entries regarding creditmemo? You can also check Apache error.log.

Comment: Ventus - add that as a question, and I'll mark it as correct... Once I'd turned on the logs and checked it's turned out as a violation on primary key on some tables... That becuase after testing the system we'd truncated a load of orders but missed the credit memo tables. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing. It sounds like your unq_increment_id has wrong value for the credit memo. 
You can find it in eav_entity_type table. You should see creditmemo. See the image below. ![enter image description here][1]

(Unfortunatelly I can't post images)

If you go right of the table you will see the unq_increment_id field. Look at your last credit memo ID from admin panel and write it to unq_increment_id.

Hope your problem is what I guessed and this solution fixes it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you check the exception log in var/log/exception.log in your project root, you might find something  like this :
**1. Exception**:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000004' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_CREDITMEMO_INCREMENT_ID'' in /var/www/html/orders/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

2. Issue - Duplicate Id for the Credit memo because the last credit memo entry to increment value was not updated in table.

**Fix:**
**Step 1** 
Go to sales/credit memo and note down the id of the last credit memo.Say X. 
**Step 2**
In DB, look in the eav_entity_type table
get the entity _type _id corresponding to Entity Type Code creditmemo . Most probably it is 7
**Step 3**
next look in the table eav_entity_store. Note down the value of increment_last_id  corresponding to the entity_type_id from the previous step.  If this value is not same as X(step1), update that row with so that the increment_last_id value is same as X

```
 UPDATE `myproject`.`eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = 'X' WHERE `eav_entity_store`.`entity_store_id` = 3;
```

Done!

Comment: I've got the exact same exception error, but in my case the increment_last_id is the same as X. What to do?